# DB2 SQL Merge Using All Fields

Tags: sql, merge, db2

I have two files that have the same layout.  I want to copy the data from the old file to the new file and bypass/ignore the duplicate keys.  Using the merge statement seems to be the best bet, but the files have over 50 fields.  Is there any way to use the merge similar to the following:

```
merge into qgpl.filea as new
using(select * from qgpl.fileb) as old
on(new.key1 = old.key1 and new.key2 = old.key2)
when not matched then insert(*)
```

I have tried everything I can think of/find to get the insert statement working without typing in all the field names.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use `insert`?

```
insert into qgpl.filea
     select b.*
     from qgpl.fileb b
     where not exists (select 1
                       from qgpl.filea a
                       where a.key1 = b.key1 and a.key2 = b.key2
                      );
```

It is a best practice to list out all the columns for the insert, just to be sure nothing unexpected happens.

Comment: When I tried the prior - a duplicate key error would generate.  The new version of the file has a different key structure.

Comment: @geojf3 . . . You probably have duplicates in `fileb`.  You need to figure out what to do about those.